# function to edit an existing note using vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

function to edit an existing note using vuejs
 WEB APP USING VUE.JS

This application allows users to do following

- Create a new note
- Show list of all created notes
- Edit an existing note
- Delete an existing note

What I was able to achieve so far

I am able to create a new note , push it into an array and also delete a note from the array . I am finding it a bit hard to edit an existing note .

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Main Div Holding our Application Data -->
    NOTE EDITOR WEB APP <br><br>
    <div id="notes">
      <!-- Panel for holding our input -->
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter notes here?" autofocus class="text-input" v-model="newNote" v-on:keyup.enter="addNote">
      <!-- Unorderd list for holding our notes -->
      <ul>
        <li v-for="Note in NoteList">
          <label for="text">{{ Note.text }}</label>
          <button v-on:click="editNote(Note)">edit</button>
          <button v-on:click="removeNote(Note)">delete</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
      //Create a new Vue instance
      new Vue({

        //Binding Vue instance to our container div with an ID of notes
        el: "#notes",
        //This is where the data for our application will be held
        data: {

          newNote: "",
          NoteList: []
        },
        //This is where we will register the methods we want to use in our      application
        methods: {
          addNote: function() {

            //trim() is used to remove whitespace from both ends of a string
            var Note = this.newNote.trim();
            //if Note is not an empty string
            if (Note) {

              //Push an object containing the Note to the NoteList array
              this.NoteList.push({
                text: Note,
              });
              //Reset newNote to an empty string so the input field is cleared
              this.newNote = "";
            }
          },
          editNote: function(Note) { 
            // how to I function editing a note
          },
          removeNote: function(Note) {

            var index = this.NoteList.indexOf(Note);
            this.NoteList.splice(index, 1);
          }
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working example - http://jsbin.com/wabepi/edit?html,js,output

Template part:

```
<!-- Main Div Holding our Application Data -->
NOTE EDITOR WEB APP <br><br>
<div id="notes">
<!-- Panel for holding our input -->
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter notes here?" autofocus class="text-input" v-model="newNote" v-on:keyup.enter="addNote">
<ul>
  <li v-for="note in notes">
    {{ note.text }} <button @click="editNote(note)">EDIT</button>
    <input type="text" v-model="note.text" @blur="doneEdit(note)" v-show="note == activeEdit">
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

JS/Vue part:

```
const app = new Vue({
  
  el: '#notes',
  
  data: {
    notes: [],
    newNote: '',
    activeEdit: null
  },
  
  methods: {
    addNote() {
      let note = this.newNote.trim()
      
      if(note) {
        this.notes.push({
          text: note
        })
        this.newNote = ''
      }
    },
    editNote(note) {
      this.activeEdit = note
    },
    doneEdit(note) {
      if (!this.activeEdit) {
        return
      }
      this.activeEdit = null
      note.text = note.text.trim()
    }
  }
  
})
```

So when user click on edit button, we are storing the text of editing note in variable called `activeEdit`.

There is one more method `doneEdit`, it takes note parameter too and update `note.text` which is attached to v-model of editing input.

You can check the official Todo MVC example, pretty same thing https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/todomvc.html

BTW: Does only I have issue with JSBin on Chrome ? Sometimes It's just show the working app, sometimes results are blank without the console issues.